# how to add Spring Sleuth into Spring Framework 5 to get traceid into logs

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth

you can find many documentation and tutorial sources on how to add spring sleuth into spring boot in order to enrich your logs with a trace-id. Thanks to spring boots auto-configuration this is done magically just by adding the sleuth dependency.

**But what about monolithic spring framework (version 5 - not Spring Boot) application?**

I tried following instructions found for spring boot, without having any effect on my logs. So I guess there few more steps which needs to be done in order to get the trace-id functionality.

I would appreciate any helpful instructions or sources which I could follow to get the trace-id into my logs from spring sleuth.

Comment: Spring Cloud Sleuth is built on Spring Boot and won't function without it. You will neet to integrate directly with brave or open telemetry